# ¿ como recorrer una matriz para mostrrar todos los registros json con un bucle?

Tags: php, html5, json, jsonobject

tengo una matriz al cual quiero acceder a todas las columnas del array json lo estoy intentando de esta forma pero solo logro acceder a una columna de la matriz ¿Cómo puedo acceder a todas las columnas de la matriz?

```
<?php

$jsonobj = '{
    "codigo": "00",
    "descripcion": "Consulta exitosa",
    "movimientos": [
        {
            "comercio_desc": "ATIPICO RIVERA",
            "fch_com": "06/01/21",
            "importe": "10000",
            "mov_tp": "D",
            "referencia_nro": "100530994259",
            "tarjeta": "6274311750000090"
        },
        {
            "comercio_desc": "COPETROL VILLA MADRID",
            "fch_com": "06/01/21",
            "importe": "350000",
            "mov_tp": "D",
            "referencia_nro": "100530994259",
            "tarjeta": "6274311750000090"
        }
    ]
}';
$decodedJson = json_decode($jsonobj, true);


?>
```

**Aqui en esta tabla deberia mostrar todos los registros**



Codigo
descripcion
comercio_desc
fch_com
importe
mov_tp
referencia_nro
tarjeta

```
        <tr>


            <td class="text-nowrap text-inverse text-center"> <?php echo $decodedJson["codigo"]; ?> </td>
            <td class="text-nowrap text-inverse text-center"> <?php echo $decodedJson["descripcion"]; ?></td>
            <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"><?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][0]["comercio_desc"]; ?> </td>
            <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"><?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][0]["fch_com"]; ?> </td>
            <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"><?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][0]["importe"]; ?> </td>
            <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"> <?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][0]["mov_tp"]; ?></td>
            <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"> <?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][0]["referencia_nro"]; ?></td>
            <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"><?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][0]["tarjeta"]; ?> </td>

            </td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda meter todo en un FOR: por ejemplo:

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($decodedJson["movimientos"]); $i++) { 
?>
//Aqui muestras los registros de tu tabla

<td class="text-nowrap text-inverse text-center"> <?php echo $decodedJson["movimientos"][$i]["comercio_desc"]; ?> </td>

<?php
}
```

Y asi muestras tus registros

Comment: Gracias Josue le puse el for y me sirvio te lo agradezco ahora estoy tratando de paginarlo ya lo estoy intentando de varias formas aun no lo logro

Comment: Usa Datatable, es easy en cuanto a html mientras sean menos de 5k registros